# How to use csurf middleware in tsoa express?

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, tsoa

I am new to tsoa and I want to do CSRF implementation in my node app. I have been able to make api using **app.use()** but I want to write in **tsoa**. Is there any way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just put what you had in a `app.use()` to the `@Middlewares()` decorator.

You can define your Middleware / Middlewares like this:

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

// ... controller logic ...

// @Get('/endpoint') | @Post('/endpoint') etc.
@Middlewares([
  (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.log(req.headers);
    next();
  },
  (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.log('Second middleware, but we can also use only one!');
    next();
  },
])
// getEndpoint(): string {
//   return 'Hello World!';
// }

// ... controller logic ...
```

*Also remember to have set the `experimentalDecorators` to `true` in your `tsconfig.json`.<sup>1</sup>*

---

<sup>1</sup> https://github.com/lukeautry/tsoa/pull/1123#issuecomment-1018251162

Answer (score 0):

In the [pre-released version](https://github.com/lukeautry/tsoa/releases/tag/v4.0.0-alpha.0), you can use the @Middlewares() decorator.

Comment: Hi @Odunsi, do you have a working example of that ? Cannot find a way to make things work on my side... Thanks !